# Performance issue with 200+ SO line items with unbound columns

Tags: acumatica

I have added two new unbound columns for SOLine DAC and updating them with in RowSelected handler. However, but it is very slow when there are more number of line items.

Here is the code for unbound columns-

```html
[System.Serializable]
public class SOLineExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
 #region UsrQtyAllocated
 public abstract class usrQtyAllocated : IBqlField { }
 protected decimal? _UsrQtyAllocated;
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty. Allocated")]
 public virtual decimal? UsrQtyAllocated { get; set; }
 #endregion

 #region UsrItemClass
 public abstract class usrItemClass : IBqlField { }
 protected string _UsrItemClass;
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Class")]
 public virtual string UsrItemClass { get; set; }
 #endregion
}
```

Here is the code snippet for RowSelected handler-

```html
protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
 SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
 if (row == null) return;

 PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLineExtension.usrQtyAllocated>(sender, row, false);
 PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLineExtension.usrItemClass>(sender, row, false);

 INItemClass defItemClass = PXSelectJoin<INItemClass,
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
  On<InventoryItem.itemClassID, Equal<INItemClass.itemClassID>>>,
  Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID);

 if (defItemClass != null)
 {
  sender.SetValue<SOLineExtension.usrItemClass>(row, defItemClass.Descr);
 }

 SOLineSplit defSOLine = PXSelectJoin<SOLineSplit,
  InnerJoin<SOLine,
  On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>,
   And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>,
   And<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<SOLineSplit.inventoryID>>>>>,
  Where<SOLineSplit.isAllocated, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.isAllocated>>,
   And<SOLineSplit.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>>,
   And<SOLineSplit.inventoryID, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.inventoryID>>>>>>.Select(Base, 1, row.OrderNbr, row.InventoryID);

 if (defSOLine != null)
 {
  sender.SetValue<SOLineExtension.usrQtyAllocated>(row, defSOLine.Qty);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should never use RowSelected handlers to set values for unbound DAC fields: RowSelected event is intended to execute only UI presentation logic. Instead it’s always recommended to assign values to unbound fields with a RowSelecting handler as shown in API Reference and Step 5.2: Customizing Business Logic for the Sales Orders form the T300 class documentation.

Also for information: none of your custom fields are decorated with PXTypeAttribute, which always a must.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. But I do not see `PXTypeAttribute` anywhere nor in any document. Can you provide an example or link.

Comment: Ruslan is referring to declaring the field type by using such examples as pxstringattribute, pxintattribute, etc.

Comment: That helped. Thank you.